# dequeuemin in Fibonacci heaps

Tags: data-structures, tree, fibonacci-heap

I wanted to ask about Fibonacci heaps.
If I have this scenario:

```
A
|
B
```

Then, we add two more nodes C and D:

```
A
|\
B C
  |
  D
```

Now we delete B:

```
A
|
C
|
D
```

Now we add E and F.

I saw it creates a tree like that:

```
E
|\
F A
  |
  C
  |
  D
```

But **I don't understand why E and F are connected with the tree**. From what I read, we connect trees with the same rank (for example, a tree of one node with another tree of one node), am I wrong?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the nodes C and D into the first Fibonacci heap, you would not end up with the tree you drew. Instead, you'd have this heap:

```
    A   C   D
    |
    B
```

Remember that Fibonacci heaps lazily add each newly added value to the top-level list of trees and only coalesce things on a deletion. If you were to delete B, you'd promote it to the top level, like this:

```
    A   B   C   D
```

You'd then remove B:

```
    A   C   D
```

Now, you'd scan the root list and coalesce the trees of the same order together. Let's suppose you scan the nodes in the order A, C, D. First, you'll coalesce A and C together, like this:

```
   A   D
   |
   C
```

At this point, no further coalesces will happen, since there's exactly one tree of each order.

If you then add in E and F, you'd put them at the top level, like this:

```
   A   D   E   F
   |
   C
```

So yes, you're right, those nodes shouldn't get added into the tree.